# Articulate Storyline - Track storyline files on multiple websites without LMS

Tags: tracking, articulate-storyline

I want to track storyline files on multiple different websites. All of the storyline files are saved on one server. I want to track how many users click the files and the timestamps. These are the options I am thinking of:

**1. Connect Google Analytics with Storyline:** This is simple and easy. But I think it would be hard to manage tens of storyline files. And I don't need detailed tracking information. I just want to know how many people click the files.

**2. Send data from storyline to MS Excel or Google Sheet:** I have some basic knowledge of JavaScript. But I don't much about MS Excel and Google Sheet.

**3. Monitor file activities on the server:** Do you know how to file the activities on the server? Do I need specific skills or software?

**4. Collect xAPI data without LMS:**

Which one do you think is better? Please let me know if you have any other suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

xAPI would be the most flexible option. By default, any project published from Storyline to xAPI will give send xAPI statements for launching the project, visiting each slide, and closing the project. You can define your own custom xAPI statements for practically anything else (i.e., clicking a button, clicking an object, submitting a quiz, etc.). You'll need an LRS account to receive those xAPI statements. I've had good luck with the free tiers on Veracity Learning, Watershed LRS, and SCORM Cloud.